# CNN,neural network angle detection

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, yolo

I have a dataset of *1000 images* of 1 soft toy from different angles. Example: [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3MFi.jpg)

I have to use some neural networks and train to detect my toy and also output its angle. I want to see: `Class Probability Angle`.
Example: [wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SynFA.jpg)

Is there a way to modify `SSD` or `YOLO` with Tensorflow or Darknet to modify framework/network to even calculate and output angle in YOLO for example?
While searching the internet I didn't find network example that will do something like that.